# How to build examples using libspotify on windows

Tags: windows, spotify

I have downloaded spotify API and am trying to build the example code using libspotify on Windows. The build environment seems to apply only for Mac/Linux world (atleast the Makefile seems to suggest that and there are no Visual Studio project files). Any one has any luck in building the sample code on Windows ?

Answer (score 2):

Even the basic stub example uses `pthreads` which is not available on windows. Since all their examples assume a POSIX compliant OS (which windows is not) I'm afraid you will not be able to build them on windows (natively). If you want try then take a look at [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/).

However, you can still use the include header file and the provided dll/lib to link against and develop applications. The library calls made in the examples are still valid - just not the examples themselves.

Comment: I did download cygwin, but still I don't think all the sample code is compilable under windows. For example, the jukebox has audio related calls which doesn't appear to be from win32 world. But I did find a visual studio project file for spshell, so it looks like the windows world may still be in transit.

Comment: You should still be able to develop using it though - just link against the .lib